# Возможно ли ускорить компиляцию Native (C++) части проекта для Android? (Windows host)

Tags: c++, windows, android-ndk

Исходные данные: Имеется кросс платформенный проект из 1500 cpp файлов (5 библиотек). 
Андроид версия строится через make (ndk-build) из под нашего скрипта на python и это невероятно долго(десятки минут).
При каждом запуске начинается молотилка "cmd->echo->cmd", когда для каждого файла создается tmp файл с флагами компиляции которые потом дергаются для сборки через make(поправьте меня если я не так понимаю как это работает)

Вопрос: Можно ли как-то избежать повторного создания этих файлов или как-то собирать вообще без их создания? Даже на шустром i7 с ssd это вызывает боль.
Пробовал поместить tmp для сборки на ram-диск, но существенного ускорения не заметил, т.к. дело(по всей видимости) не в пропускной способности ввода-вывода.
Интересует решение для Windows

Comment: Компиляция сама по себе процесс довольно долгий, особенно для крупных проектов. Для начала рекомендую убедиться, что используются многопоточная сборка, а то может просто ядра простаивают.

Comment: Используется, параллелится даже генерация промежуточных файлов для make. Но все равно процесс занимает очень много времени